# Washer not spin on all cycles

Tags: washing-machine

Washer stopped being able to spin on regular and permanent press cycles, but works fine on Hand wash cycle. Its not due to unbalanced load. Maytag LAT8826AAE

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Found two different sites that seem to suggest a broken timer for that same model:

http://forum.appliancepartspros.com/washer-repair/411851-maytag-washer-cycle-issue.html
http://www.justanswer.com/appliance/6798o-maytag-lat8826aae-will-not-rinse-drain-spin-regular.html

Which would make sense if only some modes work while others don't. It's a pretty cheap part to try replacing too (not enough rep to post 3 links, but remove the space):

partselect .com/Models/LAT8826AAE/